# Given that $f_n \to f$ in $L^1(\Omega)$, $\mu(\Omega )=1$ and $ \|f_n\|_2^2 \leq M$, show $ \|f\|_2^2 \leq M$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lp-spaces

Given that $$\int_{\Omega} |f_n -f | \, d \mu \to 0,$$ $\mu(\Omega )=1$ and $ \|f_n\|_{L^2}^2 \leq M$, show $ \|f\|_{L^2}^2 \leq M$.

Attempt:

Note first that $f_n \in L^1(\Omega)$ since
$$\|f_n \cdot 1\|_{L^1} \leq M^\frac{1}{2}$$ by C-S.
Let $1>\epsilon > 0$. Let $N \in \mathbb N$ be such that, if $n \geq N$, $$\|f_n -f\|_{L^1} < \epsilon.$$
Since $f_n \to f$ in $L^1(\Omega)$, we have that,
$$\|f\|_{L^1} \leq \|f_n-f\|_{L^1} + \|f_n\|_{L^1},$$
we see that $|f| \leq |f_n| + \epsilon$  a.e. by (i) the montonicity of the integral and (ii) since $\mu(\Omega) = 1$.

In particular, this is because $$\int_{\Omega} |f| \, d\mu \leq \int_{\Omega} |f_n| + \epsilon \, d\mu.$$

Thus, $$\|f\|_{L^2}^2 \leq \|f_n\|_{L^2}^2 + 2\epsilon\|f_n\|_{L^1} + \epsilon^2$$

Thus, we get $\|f\|_{L^2}^2 \leq M+ \epsilon$, since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary as desired.

Anything wrong with this proof? Any suggestions?

Comment: You write "since $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$ . . . we see that $|f|\le |f_n|+\epsilon$ a.e."  From $L^1$ convergence of a sequence to $0$, namely $|f_n-f|$, you seem to be inferring a.e. pointwise convergence to $0$.  I wonder why this is so.  If $g_n=f_n-f$ can't it wander back and forth across the space with its total integral diminishing but its maximum always $1$?  Say on $[0,1]$ we pick an irrational $a$, let $r_n=na-\lfloor na\rfloor\in[0,1)$, and put $g_n(x)=1$ for $r_n-1/n\le x\le r_n+1/n$, zero elsewhere.

Comment: Is it not true that if $$\int_\Omega |f| \, d \mu \leq \int_{\Omega} |f_n| + \epsilon \, d\mu$$ then $|f| \leq |f_n| + \epsilon$?

Comment: @ForgotALot I've moved the $\epsilon$ into the integral since the measure of the whole space is $1$. Sorry if that wasn't clear in the above.

Comment: Just in case, I think kobe has answered your questions better than I could have; I think we both disagree with the same point in your reasoning.

Comment: @ForgotALot Naturally, I just don't see how I'm assuming $L^1$ convergence implies a.e. pw convergence

Comment: @ForgotALot Or how your example refutes the claim that if $$\int_{\Omega} f \, d\mu \leq \int_{\Omega} g \, d \mu $$ then $f \leq g$ a.e.

Comment: @ForgotALot I agree that there is an issue.

Comment: You write "since $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$ . . . we see that $|f|≤|f_n|+ϵ$ a.e."  I guessed wrong as to what you were thinking.  To me, "$|f|≤|f_n|+ϵ$" suggested pointwise convergence, albeit only for the absolute value and only from one side, but I was wrong; I misunderstood your reasoning (but am still not convinced it's right).

Comment: @ForgotALot No it's definitely wrong, i was confusing the statement of the claim necessary for it to be true. See kobe's comments. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f_n\xrightarrow{L^1(\Omega)} f$, there is a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ of $(f_n)$ such that $f_{n_k} \rightarrow f$ pointwise a.e. on $\Omega$. By Fatou's lemma,

$$\|f\|_{L^2}^2 \le \varliminf_{k\to \infty} \|f_{n_k}\|_{L^2}^2\le \varliminf_{k\to \infty} M = M.$$

Comment: I've never seen this result of an a.e. convergent subsequence, could you provide a reference? Also, any issues with my less concise proof?

Comment: Sure. Start from page 8 of [these notes](http://www.math.psu.edu/siegel/Convergence.pdf).

Comment: As with your proof, I'm with you until you have $\|f\|_{L^1} \le \|f_n - f\|_{L^1} + \|f_n\|_{L^1}$ implies $|f| \le |f_n| + \epsilon$ a.e.. You can't choose $n$ sufficiently large at the end if you've already used $\|f_n - f\|_{L^1} < \epsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Actually, you haven't even introduced $\epsilon$ before using it.

Comment: Yes of course, this is formally wrong. But informally, if I were to pick my $\epsilon$ to be, say, $\frac{\epsilon}{4M}$, assuming $M > 1$, then we may choose our $n$ so that it is this close to $f$.

Comment: see the edits in the question

Comment: @Anthony I think I see what you're trying to use, but it's not used correctly. The result you're trying to use is that if $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions such that $\int_A f\, d\mu \le \int_A g\, d\mu$ for every measurable set $A\subset \Omega$, then $f\le g$ a.e.. However, you don't have that inequality condition satisfied.

Comment: That wouldn't get you anywhere since $A\cap \Omega = A$.

Comment: I guess I just don't see how having it work for $\Omega$ wouldn't imply it works for every measurable subset. Could you give an example?

Comment: I believe ForgotALot has given a counterexample to your claim.

Comment: I don't see how that is a counterexample to this.. I see he was showing that $L^1$ convergence does not imply a.e. pointwise. How does this show this would not work in the case of what I have done? I haven't assumed $L^1$ convergence implies a.e. convergence, unless i've done so unknowingly

Comment: @Anthony sorry I misread ForgotALot's comments. For a counterexample, let $(\Omega,\mu) = ([0,1],dx)$, $f(x) = \sin(2\pi x)$, and $g(x) = \cos(2\pi x)$. We have $\int_0^1 f(x)\, dx = 0 = \int_0^1 g(x)\, dx$, but the set of points $x\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x) > g(x)$ contains the interval $(\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{4})$, which has positive Lebesgue measure.

Comment: yeah, i made a counterexample a few moments ago. How silly of me. Though, I can't quite see how to go about this otherwise. I tried using FL, but I didn't know the above theorem. Thanks for your time.